# Why is $\lim_{n\to \infty} n\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n})} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, characteristic-functions

Why is $\lim_{n\to \infty} n\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n})} = 0$?
Can you provide a short (trivial) explanation?

The sequence in the limit only have two possible values: $0$ and $n (\to \infty)$ so it is a little confusing.

Comment: For every $x$, $n\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n})} (x)= 0$ for $n$ sufficiently large. (Consider the cases $x \leq 0$ and $x>0$).

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \leq 0$. Then, $n\chi_{(0,1/n)}(x) = n \cdot 0 = 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ as $x \not\in (0,1/n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $x > 0$. There exists some $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $0 < 1/n_{0} < x$. For all $n \geq n_{0}$, we have that $n\chi_{(0,1/n)}(x) = n \cdot 0 = 0$. This is because $x \not\in (0,1/n)$ for each $n \geq n_{0}$.

So for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq n_{0}$, we have that $n\chi_{(0,1/n)}(x) = 0 < \varepsilon$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\chi_{(0,1/n)}(x) = 0$ pointwise.

Answer (score -1):

conan gave a formal proof.  Here's a more informal way to understand why this is true.  Set $f_n(x) = n \chi_{(0, 1/n)}$.

Pointwise convergence to 0 means that, for any fixed $x$, the sequence $f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x), \dots$ ought to be a sequence which converges to 0.  Let's try this for some specific values of $x$.

- When $x=0.1$, the sequence looks like $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0,0,0,\dots$.  This converges to 0, of course.
- When $x = 0.01$, the sequence looks like $1,2,3,\dots, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, \dots$.  This also converges to $0$.
- When $x = 0.001$... you get the idea.
- When $x=0$, the sequence looks like $0,0,0,0,0,\dots$, which also converges to $0$.

So you can see that no matter what $x$ is, we get a sequence that converges to $0$.

It's true that, the smaller $x$ is, the *slower* the resulting sequence converges to 0.  But this doesn't matter when we are talking about pointwise convergence.  For *uniform* convergence, it does, and so this sequence of functions does not converge uniformly.